# How to test $q promises in angularJs with mocha, chai, sinon

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner, sinon, chai

We have just moved to mocha, chai and sinon for our test libraries and coming from jasmine i am a little confused as to how to test promises.

I have a form submit function that calls a service and on return it navigates the user to the correct state:

```
submit(event, theForm){
    event.preventDefault();

    if(theForm.$valid){
        this.AuthenticationService.authenticateUser({
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        }).then( (result) => {
            this.$state.go('dashboard.home')
        });
    }
}
```

Have gotten part of the way there with the following test:

```
it('should submit the login credentials if valid', function(){

    var dfd = q.defer(),
        promise = dfd.promise;

    controller.email = 'ryan.pays@leotech.com.sg';
    controller.password = 'Password123';

    sinon.stub(service, 'authenticateUser').returns(promise);
    sinon.spy(state, 'go');
    sinon.spy(controller, 'submit');

    controller.submit(event, theForm);

    dfd.resolve();

    expect(controller.submit).to.have.been.called;
    expect(controller.submit).to.have.been.calledWith(event, theForm);
    expect(event.preventDefault).to.have.been.called;

    expect(service.authenticateUser).to.have.been.called;
    expect(service.authenticateUser).to.have.been.calledWith({
        email: controller.email,
        password: controller.password
    });
    expect(state.go).to.have.been.called;
    expect(state.go).to.have.been.calledWith('dashboard.home');
});
```

But the assertion that `state.go` is called does not pass.  What do I change about my test to make it pass?

Comment: Hey @RyanP13 did you find solution to above problem? i am also facing the same issue. When tried to test code "authenticateUser" promise..

Answer (score 0):

Likely this is a timing issue in which your `expect()`'s are being called before the `then()` in your controller has executed. To correct this, try wrapping your `state.go` assertions in a [`finally()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback) like so:

```
it('should submit the login credentials if valid', function(){

    [...]

    return promise.finally(function() {
        expect(state.go).to.have.been.called;
        expect(state.go).to.have.been.calledWith('dashboard.home');
    );
});
```

Two important things are happening here:

1. `finally()` ensures that your `expect()`'s do not run until `dfd` has been fully resolved.
2. `finally()` returns a promise which you are then returning to the Mocha test itself. This tells Mocha that you are dealing with asynchronous code and prevents it from moving on to further tests until your `expect()`'s have executed. You can read more about handling asynchronous code in Mocha [here](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).